# How to "force convert" a value from an array of doubles into a string output in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am currently working on this program. The program outputs a country's total coarse grain production as a double value after the country's name is inputted. I am using a string array and a double array. The program runs and executes perfectly:

```
int main ()
{
    string countries[18] = {"World", "Total foreign", "United States", "Canada", "Mexico"};

    double grainsProduction[18] = {1361.4, 977.0, 384.4, 26.2, 33.2}
    string countryChoice = " ";
    int sub = 0;

    cout << "Enter country name: ";
    getline (cin, countryChoice);

    while(sub < 5 && countries[sub] != countryChoice)
    {
        sub += 1;
    }

    if (sub < 5)
    {
        cout << "" << countries[sub] << "'s coarse grain production for 2017/2018 was: " 
        << grainsProduction[sub] << " million metric tons." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid country name." << endl;
    }    
}
```

However, I would like to include another country in the countries array. This country name, when inputted, should output the statement "Not reported."

I would like to add a dummy value into the doubles array that would force convert into the string message "Not reported" if the particular country is inputted. How can this be done?

Comment: There many ways this can be done. A special constant, maybe -1, that gets translated as "not reported" by a little bit of code. This is because the fundamental laws of physics of our shared universe prohibit a country from growing a negative metric ton of grain, as such as negative value can be used to represent this condition. You can also use a `NAN`  value, perhaps. Or, with modern C++, take advantage of `std::optional` or `std::variant`, perhaps. There are many ways to do this, you need to ask a more specific question.

Comment: You can't 'force convert' a value. You have to have an if statement for the case a country isn't found and then output differently. Personally I would use and `std::map` of strings to double for what you are doing with country names mapped to grain production. That would be more efficient than using a vector in this case. If the country name exists output the grain production, but if it doesn't output 'Not reported'.

Answer (score 0):

maybe when you enter the country name you can use this code to check if there is a country with that name in the array and if there is not display your custom message.
Here is an code example:

```
  for(int x = 0; x < size; x++){
    if (countries[x].find(countryChoice, 0) != std::string::npos){
        cout << data[x] << endl;
    }
    else {

        cout << "No data for this Country" << endl;
    }
```